# Параметризованный тест в JUnit и Nan

Tags: java, junit, nan

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как правильно обрабатывать тесты, когда тестируемая функция выдаёт разные по типу результаты.
Например, есть вот такой тестируемый класс:

```
public class Calculator {    

    public Double leg(int hyp, int leg){
        if (Math.abs(hyp) < Math.abs(leg))
            return Double.NaN;
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(hyp, 2) - Math.pow(leg, 2));
    }
}
```

Вот тестовый класс:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo.closeTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CalculatorParametrizedTest {
    public Calculator calculator;
    private int hyp;
    private int leg;
    private double expected;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "Тест {index}: гипотенуза = {0}, катет = {1}, катет = {2}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> dataForTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {5, 4, 3},
                {5, -4, 3},
                {-5, 4, 3},
                {-5, -4, 3},
                {4, 5, Double.NaN},
                {3, 2, 2.24}
        });
    }

    public CalculatorParametrizedTest(int hyp, int leg, double expected){
        this.hyp = hyp;
        this.leg = leg;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        calculator = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeg(){
        assertThat(calculator.leg(hyp, leg), is(closeTo(expected, 0.1)));
    }
}
```

Не проходит тест со значением `{4, 5, Double.NaN}`. Вот описание ошибки:

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected: is a numeric value within <0.1>
>   of 
>        but: `<NaN>` differed by `<NaN>`

Я понимаю, что сравнивать NaN и NaN бессмысленно, но как правильно написать тест- не понимаю. Как правильно написать тесты для приведенной в примере функции `leg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double)) учитывает `NaN` при сравнении.

Из документации:

> NaNs are considered equal: assertEquals(Double.NaN, Double.NaN, *) passes

Пример:

```
assertEquals(expected, calculator.leg(hyp, leg), 0.1);
```

**Дополнение по матчерам**: `Matchers.closeTo` не учитывает NaN и я не нашел готового метода в hamcrest, который бы сравнивал подобным образом.

Можно написать условие самому, используя [`notANumber`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#notANumber--):

```
if(Double.isNan(expected)) {
     assertThat(calculator.leg(hyp, leg), is(notANumber()));
} else {
     assertThat(calculator.leg(hyp, leg), is(closeTo(expected, 0.1)));
}
```

, но это похоже на велосипед.

В [обсуждении похожего вопроса на Github](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/7) предлагают написать такой матчер:

```
 Matcher<Double> isCloseEnoughTo(double expected, double delta) {
      return Double.isNaN(expected) ? Matchers.notANumber() : Matchers.closeTo(expected, delta);
 }
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не подскажете, как то же самое с помощью `Matchers` сделать? И ещё, а если бы `assertEquals` тоже не мог сравнить `NaN`, как нужно было бы писать тесты в этом случае?

Comment: @woodhead Добавил в вопрос дополнение по матчерам

Comment: Не сразу понял, почему метод `Matchers.notANumber()` не определён. Оказывается, я в `maven` прописал `hamcrest-junit` версии `1.0.0.1` (в которой `notANumber()` отсутствует), а надо было `2.0.0.0`. А так всё работает. А почему вы считаете, что использование предиката `isCloseEnoughTo` лучше "велосипеда" с `if`?

Comment: @woodhead только тем, что его легче использовать повторно. Ужасного в обоих вариантах я ничего не вижу, просто странно писать в три строки то, что можно в одну.